# Installing and running .json on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, terminal, local, atom-editor, package.json

I having trouble figuring out how to run a "package.json" file locally on safari or a web browser on mac. I am new to coding, I am familiar with the terminal and I have pulled my code from the GitHub and opened it with Atom editor. However from there I have tried cmd+i to run... but gives me "Command not configured for JSON!" I thought I had installed one of the packages through atom but i guess I have not. Any way of running it through the terminal?

Comment: You cannot "run" a JSON file. A json file is merely a formatted text file — it can contain any kind of data: configuration, baseball scores, employee records, an index of cat pictures... 

So your question, as is, makes no sense. Edit your question and start over explaining what it is you're actually expecting to do, where this file is from, etc.

Comment: I have downloaded a file that is being run on a heroku server, In the file there is a package.json, and what I assume is the the source code under the file name src. The files there are a numerous files ending in .js which i assume is java script. If the is the case how does one run all of them at the same time through safari.